# how to horizontally center multiple div's in a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

I am trying to create a control which contains multiple div's and all the div's are horizontally center align. as shown below.

[image]

I was able to able to float every div using `float:left` css property. which give something like this

[image]

but ever div's are aligh left to their parent.

I have one ulternative solition to use javascript to position every div but I want to use css.
Is it possible to achive this using css.

Thanks in advance

Comment: switch from float, to display: inline-block, and text-align: center to the parent, and you should be good to go

Comment: To avoid browser issues, make sure you don't leave any white space between divs when using inline-block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may do what you are trying to:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Element 1</div>
    <div class="child">Element 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.child {
    display: inline-block;
}

.parent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apyex2tu/).